# Strange XML modification when input and output it in console app using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, console

I have a simple console app that was creted in c# using VisualStudio. It has a input parameter and return it to output.
This is the code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string msg = args[0];            
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
    }
```

Then I try to pass a param that contain a xml as string: `"<messages><message>message</message></messages>"`.  There is nothing wrong if I will use console for calling application. But in the case when I trying to debug such application I have added parameter string to *Command line arguments* on the *Debug* tab.

[image]
 After this I have got unexpected output like:

```
 ^<messages^>^<message^>message^</message^>^</messages^>
```

Why we have such output and how to overcome this? Thanks in advance.

---

The simplest solution for this issue should be replacing unwilling characters like here:

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string msg = args[0];
    Console.WriteLine(msg.Replace("^","");
}

But the reason of such behavior placed somewhere in the core of the operation system. Windows handle this situation like launch a batch file from command line with parameters. Following the link that was presented in the answer of @Artem K. you can find out that here is two way to overcome such situation. Unfortunately, no one work with this issue. Possible, because Visual Studio add something from yourself in the question how to pass args for launching batch.

Comment: I dont know what is wrong because when i run your code i am getting (<messages><message>message</message></messages>) exactly as i passed

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this. Are you using VS 2008 or VS 2010 ?

^ is the escape character in csc.exe command line.

Comment: Try it run without debugging (Ctrl + F5)

Comment: Please don't expect us to recognize that you're using Visual Studio from that screen shot alone. Your question could have been about half-a-dozen different XML development tools.

Comment: Yes, maybe you are right, I should notice about this in the question, thanks

Answer (score 1):

[How to avoid cmd.exe interpreting shell special characters like < > ^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813370/how-to-avoid-cmd-exe-interpreting-shell-special-characters-like)

Comment: I have added an image where you can see that I have already used the quotes for parameter. Am I understand your answer correctly?

Comment: No, this means “<” and “>” are special characters in windows command prompt, and Visual Studio escapes them for you using command-prompt escape character “^”.

Comment: Yes, we the reason you are right. But in which way I can getting rid off this issue in my case?

Comment: In any case thank you very much for this answer. And +1 for participated.

Answer (score 0):

in Shell, the <  and  >  has special meanings concidering steam redirection..
what makes  dir /w > myDirectory.txt possible  or   tree | more  Etc...

Follow @Artem Koshelev post to get around that.