# Batch: Escaping with caret

Tags: batch-file, cmd, piping

I've always hated batch and I still do, even for the most simple things I prefer C or PHP/Perl. But this time I could not go without it, ****sigh****.

I wanted to redirect an echo command to an other command. For example:

```
echo example | more
```

but I also wanted to be able to use special characters in the echo part of the pipe:

```
echo & | more
```

Which of course did not work. So I tried:

```
echo ^& | more
```

Which did not work either. Then by trial-and-error I found:

```
echo ^^^& | more
```

and that worked. But as interested programmer I wonder why. Why did `^&` not work and `^^^&` did?

Comment: I found this, maybe this is helpful for you?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813370/how-to-avoid-cmd-exe-interpreting-shell-special-characters-like

Comment: +1, even though you slight the beauty of almighty batch, LOL. I understand batch is extremely quirky, inconsistent, and under-documented. But then I guess the challenge is why I have so much fun with it :-)

Comment: @dbenham, Are there any attempts at documenting batch syntax from Windows?

Comment: @Pacerier - https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/1012053

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason has to do with how Windows implements pipes - Each side of the pipe is executed in its own CMD shell. Your command `echo ^& | more` actually attempts to execute

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /S /D /c" echo & "
```

on the left and

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /S /D /c" more "
```

on the right. You can see why the left hand side fails - trying to echo an unescaped `&`. The escape was consumed by the initial parsing phase before the actual left side is executed.

It is also easy to see why your solution works. The left side of `echo ^^^& | more` becomes

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /S /D /c" echo ^& "
```

There are many subtle complications when working with Windows pipes. Refer to [Why does delayed expansion fail when inside a piped block of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8192318/1012053) for more info. The selected answer has the best info, but I recommend reading the question and all answers to get the context of the selected answer.

Answer (score 5):

The first `^` is escaping the `^` character itself (the second `^`) and the third `^` is escaping the `&`.

When you run a command like `ECHO ^& | MORE`, the `^&` is replaced with `&` by the shell before the output is piped to `MORE`.

So, when you run `ECHO ^^^& | MORE`, the shell replaces `^^` with `^` and the `^&` with `&` and then pipes the output to `MORE`.

Comment: Your first paragraph's good for a [tongue-twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Piper#Lyrics)...